# Why does XStream fromXML() method throw and exception?

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, xstream

I'm trying the examples in a book dealing with serialization and deserialization to and from XML.

Why does fromXML() method (line 37) throw and exception in this code?
What could I do to have it working?

```
import java.io.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
 
public class EscribirPersonas {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File fichero = new File("FichPersona.dat");
        FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(fichero);
        ObjectInputStream dataIS = new ObjectInputStream(filein);
         
        System.out.println("Comienza el proceso...");
         
        //Creamos el objeto Lista de Personas
        ListaPersonas listaper = new ListaPersonas();
         
        try {
            while (true) {//lectura del fichero
                Persona persona = (Persona) dataIS.readObject();
                listaper.add(persona); //añadimos persona a la lista
            }
        } catch (EOFException eo) {}
        dataIS.close(); //cerrar stream de entrada
         
        try {
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            //cambiamos el nombre a las etiquetas XML
            xstream.alias("ListaPersonasMunicipio", ListaPersonas.class);
            xstream.alias("DatosPersona", Persona.class);
            //quitamos la etiqueta lista (atributo de la clase ListaPersonas)
            xstream.addImplicitCollection(ListaPersonas.class, "lista");
            //Insertamos los objetos en el XML
            xstream.toXML(listaper, new FileOutputStream("Personas.xml"));
             
            System.out.println("Creado fichero XML...");
             
            File ficheroXML = new File("Personas.xml");
            FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream (ficheroXML);
            Object o = xstream.fromXML(fis);
 
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } // fin main
} // fin clase
```

Error message:

> Comienza el proceso...
> Creado fichero XML...
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException:
> ListaPersonas at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.NoTypePermission.allows(NoTypePermission.java:26)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:74)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:135)
> at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
> at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421) at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399) at
> com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1293) at
> EscribirPersonas.main(EscribirPersonas.java:37)

Comment: Please include the exception message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen automatically when the security feature of XStream is not opening access to the class. It is to prevent severe attacks to your system.

https://x-stream.github.io/security.html#framework

You can add the permission *before* the try-block to make it work:

```
XStream.allowTypes(new Class[]{ListaPersonas.class});
```